# Kafka broker container fails with invalid argument

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I added the Kafka as docker containers

This is the docker-compose file:

```yaml
    kafka:
        image: "confluentinc/cp-kafka"
        container_name: kafka
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - zookeeper
        ports:
          - '9092:9092'
        environment:
          KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
          KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
          KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
          KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true"
          KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
          KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
          KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
          CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'false'
        networks:
          - ddn
        deploy:
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 2G
    
    init-kafka:
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
        depends_on:
          - kafka
        entrypoint: [ '/bin/sh', '-c' ]
        command: |
          "
          # blocks until kafka is reachable
          kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list

          echo -e 'Creating kafka topics'
          kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --create --if-not-exists --topic EVENT_TYPE1_NOTIFY --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

          echo -e 'Successfully created the following topics:'
          kafka-topics --bootstrap-server kafka:29092 --list
          "
        networks:
          - ddn
    
    kafka-rest:
        container_name: kafka-rest
        image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-rest
        hostname: kafka-rest
        restart: always
        depends_on:
          - init-kafka
        ports:
        - "8082:8082"
        environment:
          KAFKA_REST_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
          KAFKA_REST_HOST_NAME: kafka-rest
          KAFKA_REST_LISTENERS: http://kafka-rest:8082
          KAFKA_REST_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:29092
        healthcheck:
          test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://kafka-rest:8082/topics/EVENT_TYPE1_NOTIFY "]
          interval: 5s
          timeout: 1s
          retries: 12
        networks:
          - ddn
      
networks:
  ddn:
```

Though, while running the docker-compose inside the integration tests agent which is based on Windows server, i'm encountering the following error:

```
[2023-01-03 13:11:26,453] ERROR [KafkaApi-1] Error when handling request: clientId=1, correlationId=5, api=LEADER_AND_ISR, version=5, body=LeaderAndIsrRequestData(controllerId=1,
controllerEpoch=1, brokerEpoch=25, type=0, ungroupedPartitionStates=[], topicStates=[LeaderAndIsrTopicState(topicName='EVENT_TYPE1_NOTIFY',
topicId=MU_GDxwKTkywLg9wPNCrsg, partitionStates=[LeaderAndIsrPartitionState(topicName='EVENT_TYPE1_NOTIFY', partitionIndex=0, controllerEpoch=1,
leader=1, leaderEpoch=0, isr=[1], zkVersion=0, replicas=[1], addingReplicas=[], removingReplicas=[], isNew=true)])], liveLeaders=[LeaderAndIsrLiveLeader(brokerId=1,
hostName='kafka', port=9092)]) (kafka.server.RequestHandlerHelper)
java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(Unknown Source)
        at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:124)
        at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:54)
        at kafka.log.LazyIndex$.$anonfun$forOffset$1(LazyIndex.scala:106)
        at kafka.log.LazyIndex.$anonfun$get$1(LazyIndex.scala:63)
        at kafka.log.LazyIndex.get(LazyIndex.scala:60)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.offsetIndex(LogSegment.scala:64)
        at kafka.log.LogSegment.readNextOffset(LogSegment.scala:456)
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$recoverLog$6(Log.scala:944)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.scala:17)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at kafka.log.Log.recoverLog(Log.scala:944)
        at kafka.log.Log.$anonfun$loadSegments$3(Log.scala:824)
        at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.scala:17)
        at kafka.log.Log.retryOnOffsetOverflow(Log.scala:2494)
        at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:824)
        at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:328)
        at kafka.log.Log$.apply(Log.scala:2630)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.$anonfun$getOrCreateLog$1(LogManager.scala:830)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.getOrCreateLog(LogManager.scala:783)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLog(Partition.scala:344)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.createLogIfNotExists(Partition.scala:324)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.$anonfun$makeLeader$1(Partition.scala:563)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.makeLeader(Partition.scala:547)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.$anonfun$makeLeaders$5(ReplicaManager.scala:1568)
        at kafka.utils.Implicits$MapExtensionMethods$.$anonfun$forKeyValue$1(Implicits.scala:62)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$Node.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:633)
        at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:499)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.makeLeaders(ReplicaManager.scala:1566)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.becomeLeaderOrFollower(ReplicaManager.scala:1411)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleLeaderAndIsrRequest(KafkaApis.scala:258)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:171)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:74)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there any configuration I miss?

Comment: Are your tests written in Java? If so, use TestContainers project

Comment: I don't have a java project, I'm using SpecFlow as part of a .NET project and the docker containers are composed before the test scenarios run, and therefore it fails while trying to create the Kafka broker.

Comment: I suggest adding a version tag to your images like `7.2.3`. Perhaps latest images have a bug

Comment: This compose file looks fine, otherwise. Do you deploy to an environment with a read only filesystem? The error seems to be failing creating Kafka log directories for your topic